# Get the sms that was send

Tags: android, sms

I'm making a program that sends SMS messages on Android.
It works fine to send, but I have a little problem to know which message was sent.

The follow code is the main part of the code:
It reads many messages from the string *resp*, wait a random time and send each of them. But, I don't know which SMS the method *onReceive* is confirming.

So, this is my question: how can I know which of the SMS sends the onReceive is confirming?

I tried to look for the variables and methods of the two arguments *context* and *intent*, but it didn't help me.

```
 final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"),0);
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                
 // executed when the sms is sended
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      switch(getResultCode()){
           case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sended",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
           default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
      }
 }
 }, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));

 // resp is a String with a number and a body by line: <number><body>\n<number><body>\n...
 final Scanner scan = new Scanner(resp);        
 String to;
 String body;
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            
 while (scan.hasNext()){
      long r = new Random().nextInt(20000) + 1000;
      synchronized(this){
           try {
                this.wait(r);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR on WAIT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
      }
      to = scan.next();
      body = scan.nextLine();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending to " + to,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
      sms.sendTextMessage(to, null, body, pi, null);
 }
 scan.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Slightly modified the code to be able to save the BroadcastReceiver for purposes of unregistering**

You can do this either by adding "extras" to the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` or by encoding the message ID in the "ACTION" that you put in the `Intent` that you pass to `getBroadcast()`.

Using "extras" is more complicated due to the how extras are handled in `PendingIntent`s. Here's an example of what I mean by encoding the message ID in the ACTION:

```
long messageID = ...; // This is the message ID (some unique value so that you know which message was sent)
String actionString = "SMS_SENT_" + messageID;

final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(actionString),0);
BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    // executed when the sms is sended
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract message ID from action
        String action = intent.getAction();
        long id = -1; // Message ID
        if (action != null) {
            id = Long.parseLong(action.substring(9));
            // id is now your message ID
        }
        switch(getResultCode()){
           case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sended",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
           default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(actionString));
// Here you can save myBroadcastReceiver somewhere (in an ArrayList maybe?)
//  so that you can unregister later
```

Comment: Seems cool. I already have a unique id for each SMS, cause all the messages are on a database... So, I'll need one PendingIntent for each SMS ?  I'll try it and come back to give you some feedback. Thanks.

Comment: there is something strange... I need to register one _onReceive_ for each SMS? It isn't working properly. The first onReceive is executed, but the app "dead" before execute the others...  Some idea ?  Thank you again.

Comment: Do you know anyway to **unregister** a receiver (the inverse operation of the _registerReceiver_) ?  Cause I think that I can save memory making it, cause I actually register a lot of receivers (one for each message...)

Comment: Of course. You can unregister the receiver the same way. You'll need to save a reference to the `BroadcastReceiver` you created and then when you want to unregister, just call `unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver)`. I edited my answer to show how to do this.